# How to pass jquery variable on controller of codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have problem on passing jquery variable on codeigniter controller. actually i want to retrive value from dropdown and send to via onclick event. i am able to pass value to jscript but i am unable to pass to controller file.

My view file is:

```
<select name="cities" id="cities" onChange="change_city();">    
    <option value="Basel">Basel</option>
    <option value="Bern">Bern</option>
    <option value="Fribourg">Fribourg</option>
    <option value="Geneva">Geneva</option>
    <option value="Lugano">Lugano</option>
    <option value="Zurich">Zurich</option>
</select>
```

my jscript is:

```
function change_city(){
    var home_city =$("#cities option:selected").val();
    var params = 'city='+home_city;
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: lang+"/webshop/change_city",
       data: params,
       success: function( r ) {
         $('#ajax_msg').html( r );
         location.reload( true );
       }
    });
}
```

and controller is:

```
function change_city(){
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $expire = 9999999999;

        setcookie("home_city", $city, $expire);
    }
```

Need help !!

Comment: did you try using `$this->input->post('city');` instead of `$_POST['city']`?

Comment: How far is the script getting? Where is it failing? Is the AJAX URL correct?

Comment: its working up to jquery. and value is not passed to controller function of codeingniter. ajax url is correct.

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.5+, could you try adding the `cache: false` option on your AJAX request ?

Comment: I just tested it and it should work, are you sure your url is good ? Maybe you forget the index.php part in your ajax url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with codeigniter but it does look good to me but have you tried object syntax?

```
data: ({city: home_city}),
```